# Replace each line with different text using 'sed' (shell script)

Tags: shell, unix, replace, sed

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
    <root>
       <station name = "insert_text"/>
       <station name = "insert_text"/>
       <station name = "insert_text"/>
    </root>
```

I wanted to replace the text "insert_text" with the values from a text file which looks like:

```
    Station1
    Station2
    Station3
```

After reading the input file above, the generated XML file should look like:

```
    <root>
       <station name = "Station1"/>
       <station name = "Station2"/>
       <station name = "Station3"/>
    </root>
```

The script I now use is as follows and it replaces all the 3 lines only with 'Station1'.

```
    while read a
    do 
        sed -i -e "s/insert_text/$a/g" filename.xml
    done<inputfile.txt
```

What should I change in order to replace each of the lines in the XML file with different texts?

Comment: Every time you write a loop in shell to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. See for example http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice. This is a job for awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

The issue with your code is that once it replaces `insert_text` in the file, there are no more `insert_text`s to be replaced by `Station2` and `Station3`.

**Solution**

The solution is to quit the replacing once the first `insert_text` has be replaced, and read the next line from the file

You can do this by

```
while read a;     
do          
   sed  "1,/insert_text/ s/insert_text/$a/; " input;     
done < file
```

**What it does?**

- `1,/insert_text/` This is an address range, tells the sed to do the replacing from the line 1 till the first `insert_text`. No other `insert_text`s are replaced

**OR**

```
sed  "/insert_text/{s/insert_text/$a/;q;}" input;
```

Comment: Good approach, but I would implement this with `sed "/insert_text/{s//$a/g; q;}"`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yeah, that should work in gnu-sed, I was testing in BSD sed and was not able to make it work.

Comment: Aside from the pointless use of `g`, what @WilliamPursell suggests _does_ work with BSD Sed. Generally, though, calling Sed in a loop will be very slow for anything other than small files.

Comment: P.S.: BSD Sed requires the last command in a  block to be `;`-terminated, unlike GNU Sed (`... q; }` vs. `{ ... q }`). That's why @WilliamPursell's command works even with BSD Sed, but the one you quoted in your answer does not. Also note his omission of the regex in the `s//` call, which conveniently reuses the one that was used to match the line.

Comment: @mklement0 - I was just going to point that out; you beat me to it. Thanks for keeping the torch burning for us BSD users.  ;-)

Comment: @mklement0 The `;` was something that I missed :(. Thanks for the tip that `s//` will replace the already matched pattern. That was new for me

Comment: The `1,` seems superfluous, too. And the braces can be avoided altogether; `"/insert_text/!b;s//$a/;q"` ... But fundamentally, rewriting the file onmpteen times seems misdirected.

Answer (score 3):

I think `awk` is better suited for this task:

**Demo**

```
$ cat inputfile.dat 
Station1
Station2
Station3
$ cat filename.xml 
   <root>
       <station name = "insert_text"/>
       <station name = "insert_text"/>
       <station name = "insert_text"/>
    </root>


$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[++c]=$1;next}/station name/{sub("insert_text",a[++i])}1' inputfile.dat filename.xml 
   <root>
       <station name = "Station1"/>
       <station name = "Station2"/>
       <station name = "Station3"/>
    </root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another awk take on this...  Rather than reading one file into a an array in memory and then reading the second file for text to replace, you can stream through both files at once:

```
$ cat inp1
Station1
Station2
Station3
$ cat inp2
    <root>
       <station name = "insert_text"/>
       <station name = "insert_text"/>
       <station name = "insert_text"/>
    </root>
$ awk -vtext="insert_text" '$0~text{getline stn <"inp1"; sub(/insert_text/,stn)} 1' inp2
    <root>
       <station name = "Station1"/>
       <station name = "Station2"/>
       <station name = "Station3"/>
    </root>
```

This approach will be advantageous if your list of stations is larger than you can comfortably fit in memory.

Broken out for easier reading, here's what the script does:

```
$0 ~ text {                 # run these commands if we find your text
  getline stn <"inp1"       # read a new input line from the file "inp1"
  sub(/insert_text/,stn)    # do the substitution.
}
1                           # shorthand for "print the current line".
```